# Reliable TCP server in Linux using C

Tags: linux, nonblocking, tcpserver

I have written a simple TCP server C program which listens for connections on port 4500 and it works fine.

Now while waiting for a client to connect if I restart the internet services and then try to connect to server it should connect. Can anyone suggest how to do it as I am not getting it. I have read the beej's guide to make the calls non-blocking but it is making only read call non-blocking whereas I think I have to make `accept()` non-blocking.